# Linux Fedora Terminal

Tags: linux, fedora, terminal

I already installed Linux Fedora for learning Ethical Hacking course on YouTube. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vg9cNFPQFqM).

My problem is that, for the course I need also Kali Linux environment on VirtualBox. I started VirtualBox on my Fedora OS, but when I want to run Kali Linux on VirtualBox in the screen `Kernel Driver Not installed  rc=-1908` error appeared.

I found some ways for resolving this error on YouTube and on this blog, but unfortunately the commands most of them don't work on my Fedora terminal.

I don't know how to solve it. The main problem is that when I typed some commands, my terminal can't recognize this commands, without these commands I cannot learn my course and I can’t run Kali Linux on VirtualBox.

Please help me I want my terminal to work PROPERLY.

Comment: Imho, that downvote was a bit harsh. This one is using Kali as it was designed to be used, besides, his error is on Fedora (upvoting to compensate). It would be nice Derya if you could tell us what you tried and what errors you got ;-).

Comment: @thecarpy will upvoting for the same reason after the question is cleaned up a bit.

Comment: Derya, you should try `sudo yum install make automake gcc gcc-c++ kernel-devel`  and  `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup` 

@jdwolf np

Comment: @thecarpy I don't think they are referring to Fedora. They were just saying they ran Fedora and it worked.

Comment: I'm... pretty sure.. this is caused by version mismatch between virtual box guest additions on the host and guest?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/41118/virtualbox-kernel-driver-not-installed

Comment: that ended quickly

Comment: Do you _need_ VirtualBox? Why not install Kali using Boxes or Virt-Manager as included with Fedora? It should have no problem running Kali.

Answer (score 2):

Let's get this question in parts, because you seem to throw everything together into a single "my terminal does not work".

First step: you need to understand the difference between the terminal, the shell and the programs that you run. You typed "some commands" in the terminal and "it didn't work". When you type `ls`, or `ls /` you should see a list of files and directories. Does that work? In that case, your terminal works, your shell works and at least `ls` works.

Try `lsmod | more` as command. This should give you some output like:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
tun                    20475  2
cdc_acm                19395  0
pci_stub                1806  1
vboxpci                16252  0
vboxnetadp             19493  0
vboxnetflt             19295  0
vboxdrv               418989  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
-- More --
```

For me, this shows that the `vboxdrv` module is installed and running. Your original error was `Kernel Driver Not installed rc=-1908`, so the `vboxdrv` probably won't be in your list. You can insert the module with `insmod vboxdrv`, which must be done as root. Look carefully at the error message; I would guess it has something  to do with version numbers, but it also could be that the module is not available.

I will not go into the way that kernel modules should be compiled and why you probably need the kernel source available for that. I will suggest that you remove your current virtualbox installation and install from the repositories:
(as root:)

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
wget http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/rpm/fedora/virtualbox.repo
dnf update
rpm -qa kernel |sort -V |tail -n 1
uname -r
# The kernel versions from the last two commands should match
dnf install binutils gcc make patch libgomp glibc-headers glibc-devel kernel-headers kernel-devel dkms
dnf install VirtualBox-5.2
/usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup
usermod -a -G vboxusers your_name
```

and then you should be able to run VirtualBox.

I would suggest that you make yourself a bit more familiar with Linux before entering the Kali adventure. Kali is not a distribution for beginners. Also, the time spent on getting familiar with Linux will help you with your CEH-studies.

Comment: Thank you for patience and explanation. It works for me.

Comment: Derya, if this answer solved your issue, then please mark it as such ... thanks in advance!